# Check if two semistandard Young tableaux are compatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I have a question about how to check if two tableaux are compatible (will define below).  Here we only consider tableaux of rectangular shape.

A tableau is called semistandard if its rows are weakly increasing and columns are strictly increasing. We say that a semistandard Young tableau has small gap if it is one column and its content is obtained by removing a number from a set of consecutive numbers. So a small gap tableau has only one gap and the gap is only one element. For example, one-column tableau with content [1,2,3,5] is a small gap tableau. The gap is {4}.

For two semistandard Young tableaux \$T, T'\$, we denote by \$T \cup T'\$ the tableaux whose rows are unions of corresponding rows of \$T, T'\$ and reorder the union such that it is weakly increasing. The resulting tableau is semistandard. Denote by \${\rm SSYT}(k, [n])\$ the set of rectangular semistandard Young tableaux with k rows and with entries in \$[n]=\{1, \ldots, n\}\$.

Given two k-element subsets I and J of \$\{1, \ldots, n\}\$, denote by min(J) the minimal element in J and by max(I) the maximal element in I, we write I < J if max(I)<min(J). The sets I and J are called weakly separated if at least one of the following two conditions holds:

\$J-I\$ can be partitioned into a disjoint union \$J-I = J' \sqcup J''\$ so that \$J' < I-J < J''\$;

\$I-J\$ can be partitioned into a disjoint union \$I-J = I' \sqcup I''\$ so that \$I' < J-I < I''\$.

Let \$T, T' \in {\rm SSYT}(k, [n])\$ with decomposition into unions of one-column small gap tableaux \$T=T_1 \cup \cdots \cup T_r\$, \$T'=T'_1 \cup \cdots \cup T'_{r'}\$, where the factors are written in the lexicographical order \$T_i < T_{i+1}\$, \$T'_{i}<T'_{i+1}\$.

We denote by \${\rm LC}(T, T')\$ the following condition: there is an injective map \$f: X_{T,T'} \to Y_{T,T'}\$, \$f(i,j)=(i',j')\$, such that for any \$(i,j) \in X_{T,T'}\$, either \$i=i'\$, \$T'_{j'}\$ and \$T'_{j}\$ are not weakly separated, and \$\min T'_j < \min T'_{j'}\$ or \$j=j'\$, \$T_i\$ and \$T_{i'}\$ are not weakly separated, and \$\min T_{i'}< \min T_i\$, where \$X_{T,T'}, Y_{T,T'}\$ are two sets depending on T, T'.
For simplicity, I will give the sets \$X_{T,T'}, Y_{T,T'}\$ directly below.

I wrote a program to check the property \${\rm LC}(T, T')\$. I tried my best to make it fast. But maybe it can still be improved. My codes are below

```
import itertools

def is_weakly_separated(I,J): # I,J have the same size
    r1 = sorted(set(I).difference(J))
    r2 = sorted(set(J).difference(I))

    if not r1 or not r2:
        return True

    if r1[0] >= r2[0]:
        r1, r2 = r2, r1
 
    for i in range(len(r1) - 1):
        if r2[0] < r1[i+1]: 
            return r2[-1] <= r1[i+1]
 
    return r1[-1] <= r2[0]

def is_LCTTprime_new(a, b, g1, g2, n): # a, b are sets, g1, g2 are two small gap tableaux
    r=0
    if len(a)>len(b):
        r=0
    elif len(a)==0:
        r=1
    else:

        r1=[]
        for p1 in a:
            t1=[]
            for p2 in b:
                i=p1[0]-1
                j=p1[1]-1
                i1=p2[0]-1
                j1=p2[1]-1
                if ( i==i1 and is_weakly_separated(g2[j1], g2[j])==0 and g2[j][0]<g2[j1][0] ) or ( j==j1 and is_weakly_separated(g1[i], g1[i1])==0 and g1[i1][0]<g1[i][0] ):
                    t1.append(p2)
            
            if t1==[]: 
                r=0
                return r
                break
            r1.append(t1) 

        r3=Cartesian_product_of_lists_in_a_list(r1) 
        for i in r3:
            t1=remove_duplicates_list_of_lists(list(i))
            if len(t1)==len(a): 
                r=1
                return r
                break
    return r 

def Cartesian_product_of_lists_in_a_list(l): # l=[l1,l2,...], l1 is a set written in terms of a list
 
    r=[]
    for i in itertools.product(*l):
        r.append(i)

    return r 

def remove_duplicates_list_of_lists(l): # very fast
    l.sort()
    r=list(l for l,_ in itertools.groupby(l))

    return r
```

We test the program below.

```
n=9
g1=[[1,2,4,5],[2,3,4,6],[3,4,6,7],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[5,6,7,9],[5,6,8,9]]
g2=[[1,2,4,5],[3,5,6,7],[4,6,7,8],[5,7,8,9]]
X=[[2,1],[3,1],[4,2],[5,2],[6,3],[7,3]]
Y=[[1,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,3],[6,4],[7,4]]
is_LCTTprime_new(X, Y, g1, g2, n)
```

The above is fast. But the following is slow.

```
n=9
g1=[[1,2,3,5],[2,3,4,6],[2,4,5,6],[3,4,6,7],[3,5,6,7],[3,5,6,7],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[4,6,7,8],[5,6,7,9],[5,6,7,9],[5,6,8,9],[5,6,8,9]]
g2=[[1,2,3,5],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[2,3,4,6],[2,3,4,6],[2,4,5,6],[2,4,5,6],[3,4,5,7],[3,4,6,7],[3,5,6,7],[3,5,6,7],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[4,5,7,8],[5,6,7,9],[5,6,8,9],[5,6,8,9]]
X=[[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,8],[4,9],[5,2],[5,3],[5,8],[5,9],[6,2],[6,3],[6,8],[6,9],[7,6],[7,7],[7,11],[7,12],[7,13],[8,6],[8,7],[8,11],[8,12],[8,13],[9,6],[9,7],[9,11],[9,12],[9,13],[10,6],[10,7],[10,11],[10,12],[10,13],[11,1],[11,12],[11,13],[12,14],[12,15],[12,16],[13,14],[13,15],[13,16],[14,10],[14,11],[14,14],[14,15],[14,16],[15,10],[15,11],[15,14],[15,15],[15,16]]
Y=[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,6],[2,7],[2,8],[2,9],[3,2],[3,3],[3,8],[3,9],[4,6],[4,7],[4,11],[4,12],[4,13],[5,1],[5,12],[5,13],[6,1],[6,12],[6,13],[7,10],[7,11],[7,14],[7,15],[7,16],[8,10],[8,11],[8,14],[8,15],[8,16],[9,10],[9,11],[9,14],[9,15],[9,16],[10,10],[10,11],[10,14],[10,15],[10,16],[11,6],[11,7],[11,11],[12,17],[12,18],[12,19],[13,17],[13,18],[13,19],[14,14],[14,15],[14,16],[14,18],[14,19],[15,14],[15,15],[15,16],[15,18],[15,19]]
is_LCTTprime_new(X, Y, g1, g2, n)
```

Do you have some suggestions to increase the speed? Thank you very much.

Edit:

The original function is_LCTTprime_new used the following codes

```
r3=Cartesian_product_of_lists_in_a_list(r1) 
for i in r3:
    t1=remove_duplicates_list_of_lists(list(i))
    if len(t1)==len(a): 
        r=1
        return r
        break
```

which takes long time. This problem can be solved by using the maximum matching problem. I used the codes in [www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/) and modified the function `is_LCTTprime_new` in the question.

```
def is_LCTTprime_new(a, b, g1, g2, n): # a, b are sets, gg1, gg2 are two small gap tableaux
    r=0 
    
    if len(a)>len(b):
        r=0
    elif len(a)==0:
        r=1
    else:

        r1=[]
        for pp1 in range(len(a)):
            p1=a[pp1]
            t1=[]
            for pp2 in range(len(b)):
                p2=b[pp2]
                i=p1[0]-1
                j=p1[1]-1
                i1=p2[0]-1
                j1=p2[1]-1
                if ( i==i1 and is_weakly_separated(g2[j1], g2[j])==0 and g2[j][0]<g2[j1][0] ) or ( j==j1 and is_weakly_separated(g1[i], g1[i1])==0 and g1[i1][0]<g1[i][0] ):
                    t1.append(pp2)
            
            if t1==[]: # can speed up the computations
                r=0
                return r
                break
            r1.append(t1)

        bipartite=matrix_from_edge_set_of_bipartite_graph(r1,len(a),len(b))
        g=BipartiteGraphMaxMatching(bipartite)
        num=g.maxBPM()
        if num==len(a):
            r=1
        else:
            r=0
    return r 


class BipartiteGraphMaxMatching:
    def __init__(self,graph): # graph is given by list of lists, it is a bipartite graph, graph[i][j]=1 means xi is connected to yj 
         
        # residual graph
        self.graph = graph
        self.ppl = len(graph)
        self.jobs = len(graph[0])
 
    # A DFS based recursive function
    # that returns true if a matching
    # for vertex u is possible
    def bpm(self, u, matchR, seen):
 
        # Try every job one by one
        for v in range(self.jobs):
 
            # If applicant u is interested
            # in job v and v is not seen
            if self.graph[u][v] and seen[v] == False:
                 
                # Mark v as visited
                seen[v] = True
 
                '''If job 'v' is not assigned to
                   an applicant OR previously assigned
                   applicant for job v (which is matchR[v])
                   has an alternate job available.
                   Since v is marked as visited in the
                   above line, matchR[v]  in the following
                   recursive call will not get job 'v' again'''
                if matchR[v] == -1 or self.bpm(matchR[v], matchR, seen):
                    matchR[v] = u
                    return True
        return False
 
    # Returns maximum number of matching
    def maxBPM(self):
        '''An array to keep track of the
           applicants assigned to jobs.
           The value of matchR[i] is the
           applicant number assigned to job i,
           the value -1 indicates nobody is assigned.'''
        matchR = [-1] * self.jobs
         
        # Count of jobs assigned to applicants
        result = 0
        for i in range(self.ppl):
             
            # Mark all jobs as not seen for next applicant.
            seen = [False] * self.jobs
             
            # Find if the applicant 'u' can get a job
            if self.bpm(i, matchR, seen):
                result += 1
        return result

def matrix_from_edge_set_of_bipartite_graph(l,n,m): # here n=len(l), l = [[2,4,5],[2,3],...] means vertex x1 connect to y2, y4, y5, vertex x2 connect to y2, y3 
    #print('l',l)
    r=[]
    for i in range(n):
        t1=[]
        for j in range(m):
            t1.append(0)
        r.append(t1)
    #print(r)
    for i in range(n):
        #print(i)
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            #print('j', j, l[i][j])
            r[i][l[i][j]]=1
    return r
```